# wp_insert_post questions

Tags: wp-insert-post

I'm trying to add posts using `wp_insert_post`, but a few issues occur.

First the code:

```
function importposts() {

    $fh_import = @fopen( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/importposts.txt', 'r' );

    if ( $fh_import ) {
        while ( ( $line = fgets( $fh_import ) ) !== false ) {
            $ids = explode( '*', $line );
            array_walk( $ids, 'trim' ); 

$postdate = date('2014-06-19 00:30:00');
$postdate_gmt = date('2014-06-19 04:30:00');

$post = array(
  'post_content'   => $ids[2],
  'post_name'      => $ids[5],
  'post_title'     => $ids[0],
  'post_status'    => 'draft',
  'post_type'      => 'post',
  'post_author'    => '5',
  'ping_status'    => 'closed',
  'to_ping'        => 'http://rpc.pingomatic.com/',
  'post_date_gmt'  => $postdate_gmt,
  'post_date'  => $postdate,
  'post_category'  => array($ids[6]),
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
update_field( "field_1", $ids[0], $post_id );

$myFile = "postid.txt";
$fh_export = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $post_id.'@'.$ids[5].'\n';
fwrite($fh_export, $stringData);
fclose($fh_export);
        }
    }

    }
```

And here's an example of what the `importposts.txt` file looks like:

```
text-text with line breaks???-text-text-text-text-11,12,13,14
text-text with line breaks???-text-text-text-text-11,12,13,14
text-text with line breaks???-text-text-text-text-11,12,13,14
```

**The questions:**

1. The second field in the text file is the actual body of the post - how could I insert line break symbols into it, without actually breaking the line of the text file, but I still need the post to have line breaks?
2. The last field contains all the category id's seperated by comma - I don't know how many categories each post has so I have to put them all into one single field. Is it possible to assigna a variable inside an array like this: `'post_category'  => array($ids[6])` or what other alternative are there?
3. Any ideas why nothing is written to `postid.txt` and no errors given?

Comment: You lost me a little. :) Do you want line breaks in your text source file?.. Then use some data format that is line-break-friendly?

Comment: No, I don't want line breaks in the text file, as I'm using it as a "CSV" file. But I want to create the post with line breaks - i.e. for paragraphs.

Comment: I tried adding \n into the text file where I needed line breaks for example: `text-text\nwith\nline\nbreaks-text-text-text-text-11,12,13,14` but it doesn't result in new lines in the created post - just the letters `n`